# LINQ to SQL DataContext seems to lock when iterating foreach on a Where statement

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I am doing a simple foreach loop on a table in my database, however, if I try to do any other queries against the database while inside that loop, it seems that the database (or possibly only my `DataContext`) is locked.

My tables in question are a *Process* table (about 44,000 rows) and a child *ProcessValidation* table (about 133,000 rows).  ProcessValidation has a valProcessKey that points back to Process and has an index applied against it.  My code is as follows:

```
using (var dbContext = new BTR.Data.Legacy.DataContexts.xDS.DataContext(connectionString) { DeferredLoadingEnabled = false, ObjectTrackingEnabled = false })
{
    var dataLoadProcesses = 
        dbContext.Processes
                 .Where(p => new[] { "UpdateProcess", "RBLProcess", "RBLCalcProcess" }.Contains(p.procType));

    // All these count queries work outside of the foreach  
    Console.WriteLine(dataLoadProcesses.Count());
    Console.WriteLine(dbContext.ProcessValidations.Count());
    Console.WriteLine(dbContext.ProcessValidations.Count(v => v.valProcessKey == 1591));

    foreach (var process in dataLoadProcesses)
    {
        // can grab fields from 'process' object

        // can *NOT* execute any other queries against ProcessValidation
    }
}
```

Inside my `foreach`, I can grab fields from each process row and everything works fine, but if I try querying database again it locks up.  For example, a simple count query like below never returns and just locks up (I think eventually it actually gave me an `OutOfMemoryException`).

```
var existingValidations = 
    dbContext.ProcessValidations.Count(v => v.valProcessKey == process.procKey);
```

I tried using an `TransactionScope` around the query to effectively issue a `NOLOCK` command, but that didn't help either.

Above, I said possible only the `DataContext` was locked because while it is locked, I executed a Count() query against the database in a LINQPad script using a different `DataContext` and it returned immediately (even though the original `DataContext` was still spinning)

It was suggested that this might be a duplicate of [Processing large datasets using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1705273/processing-large-datasets-using-linq) but I don't think it applies.

1. I created my context outside the loop
2. It locks up on first Count() query.

After I get past problem of that, creating a compiled query might help performance and memory consumption, but I'm not to that point yet

Comment: are you trying to access the datacontext outside of it's creation scope?

Comment: No, that would be a compile error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Processing large datasets using LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1705273/processing-large-datasets-using-linq)

Comment: @KadirLüzumlar I don't think exact problem.  It could help later one, but a) I created my context outside the loop, and b) it locks up on *first* `Count()` query.  After I get past problem of that, creating a compiled query might help performance and memory consumption, but I'm not to that point yet.

Comment: Have you got an index on 'procType'?

Comment: @Phil I didn't.  I've added one and get the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that LINQ is fetching a LOCK. You can easily avoid it by using `foreach (var process in dataLoadProcesses.ToList())`. In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37160608/3866548) answer you have a little explanation. I don't think its enough, because I don't understand how can a `for-each` block a `count`, but it is a start.

If you want/need your query not to block the database at all, I found [this](http://ryancoder.blogspot.pe/2010/06/execute-linq-queries-without-locking.html) other link.

Both of this solutions must bring the entire query before processing it, and there probably is a better solution.

Comment: I tried the TransactionScope method you linked and it had no affect.